# Searching log file based on pattern, then searching in reverse for specific text

Tags: powershell

I am reading a log file that looks like this:

```
2019-01-22 13:58:01,524 [1] DEBUG BuH.Sync.Json.ImportSet [(null)] - Import #12344453467612341
2019-01-22 13:58:01,735 [1] DEBUG BuH.Sync.Json.ImportSet [(null)] - Log Stuff
2019-01-22 13:58:01,742 [1] DEBUG BuH.Sync.Json.ImportItem [(null)] - Log Stuff
2019-01-22 13:58:01,761 [1] DEBUG BuH.Sync.Json.BusinessObjects.Adresse [(null)] - Log Stuff
2019-01-22 13:58:01,781 [1] INFO  BuH.Sync.Json.Mapping.Converter2 [(null)] - Log Stuff
2019-01-22 13:58:01,785 [1] ERROR BuH.Sync.Json.Mapping.Json.JsonAdressConverter [(null)] - LOG SYSTEM ERROR CODE
2019-01-22 13:58:01,894 [1] DEBUG BuH.Sync.Json.ImportSet [(null)] - Import #9546181668418643
2019-01-22 13:58:01,896 [1] DEBUG BuH.Sync.Json.ImportSet [(null)] - Log Stuff
2019-01-22 13:58:01,897 [1] DEBUG BuH.Sync.Json.ImportItem [(null)] - Log Stuff
2019-01-22 13:58:01,902 [1] ERROR BuH.Sync.Json.Mapping.Json.JsonAdressConverter [(null)] - LOG SYSTEM ERROR CODE
```

I am able to easily find the **ERROR** lines with `Get-Content .\JSON.log | ? {($_ | Select-String “Error”)}` however for the email report I want to prepare, I need the line with the corresponding *Import #* that preceeded it. I cannot use `-context` as the lines between the error and the import number line fluctuate.

Is it possible to search through a log, find the string, then search backwards for another string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you filter the log to only show lines that match "ERROR" or "Import #" then you can use the index of the ERROR line to retrieve the previous line. This line should be the import line as we are filtering the log only to show imports and errors.

This is making an assumption based on the log you have sent. It is possible this may not work if the log contains other lines that match these patterns that are not relevant to our lookup.

```
# Get content from log file where line matches 'ERROR' or 'Import #'

$log = gc c:\log.txt | ? { $_ -cmatch 'Import #' -or $_ -cmatch 'ERROR' }

# For each line in log file

foreach($l in $log)
{
    # If it matches ERROR

    if($l -cmatch 'ERROR')
    {
        # Return the previous line

        $log[$log.IndexOf($l)-1]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Adam Works in this special case only, because the log lines should be unqiue (but only because of the timestamp). Else `IndexOf` can return the wrong line. (You could iterate using a regular `for`, then you already have the index.) Also, this is pretty imperformant, converting to an array first, then iterating the array *again*, AND using the indexOf, which can take a while, depending on the amount of lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this (better performance):

```
.\JSON.log | foreach {
    # error record found
    if ($_ -match "Error") {
         Write-Host "Import: $importLine"
         Write-Host "Error: $_"
    }
    # if "Import" occurence found, remember it and continue
    elseif ($_ -match "Import #") {
        $importLine = $_
    }
}
```